# batch file to read specific letters from a text file?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I have a txt file called named.txt Is there a way to create a batch file to read every  letters 2 through 7 letters  from every line from name.txt  and ignore the rest and output it onto  a different txt file called name2.txt. For example I have  this in the txt file:

G2010060sample.png
G2010061sample.png
G2010062sample.png
G2010063sample.png

and the batch file would  create a new txt file like this :

2010060.png
2010061.png
2010062.png
2010063.png

Comment: What operating system are you using ? Windows, Unix-like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excellent online ressource http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html

```
@echo off
if exist output.txt del output.txt
for /f "delims=" %%i in (input.txt) do call :ParseLine %%i
goto :eof


:ParseLine
set line=%1
set line=%line:~1,7%
echo %line%.png>> output.txt
goto :eof
```

Comment: Thanks you so much!! works great but there a problem. When I run it again it repeats the names all over. Is there a way to stop repeating the names.  It shows  2010060.png
2010061.png
2010062.png
2010063.png2010060.png
2010061.png
2010062.png
2010063.png

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean by repeating names. This very simple batch takes your input.txt and generates an output.txt... if the names repeat themselves in input.txt that is a shame. You may want to create your input.txt automatically with a line like this: dir /b G*.png>input.txt    just before using input.txt in the for /f.

Answer (score 0):

```
cut -b 2-7,15-18 < infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

Comment: The 15-18 part is only guaranteed to get the extension if the filenames are all 14 chars long.

Comment: Plus cut is not available on Windows unless you install it with cygwin or something similar.